# Rewiring screw less lamp socket, how do I remove wires?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, lamp

I bought a light kit from World Market to replace my current set up and opened the socket to rewire to find no easy way to remove the wires from the socket... How do I get them out? There is no visible means of releasing them and I don't want to just yank them. Has anyone seen this sort of socket before?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I stuck a paper clip in the same hole as the wire and it came right out.

Answer (score 4):

Open one leg of a paper clip and insert it into the little notch next to the wire. The wire should pop right out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing a new socket (what I assume you mean by a "light kit" would include one, and I assume that the pictured one is the old one), just cut it off (and strip a little more insulation from it) if you can't get Speedy Petey's trick to work.

Don't forget to look inside the socket as another place release holes could be (but probably aren't) hiding.

Answer (score 0):

That end doesn't look field-modifiable; cut the plug off and rewire *it*.